# Python script runs in RPi 2 but not RPi 3

Tags: python, bluetooth

I used the code provided in [this tutorial](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-the-raspberry-pi) and successfully ran it on the RPi 2 but when I follow the same steps on the RPi 3 it won't work. The shell just says:

```
>>>=====RESTART=====
>>>
>>>
```

I noticed something else too:

1. Image used in tutorial is Wheezy but RPi 3 apparently doesn't support it
2. In step 4 `main.conf` doesn't have the line `#DisablePlugins = network,input` so I added it

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your going to need to be a bit more specific as to where your problem occurs.

Comment: When I run the script on RPi 2, Python shell displays expected string. When I run the script on RPi 3 the shell only reads RESTART.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are using?, I don't feel like putting the code together myself. Also do you not get any error when running the code? Because I see nowhere in the code where it would print "=====RESTART=====" is their something that I'm missing? Also what command(s) are you using to run your code?

Comment: code: http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/PiTooth.zip

Comment: Yeah, your going to need to paste it here, I can't exactly download and open zip files on my phone.